# $user = $facebook->getUser() returns 0 with SDK 3.2.2

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I m using the facebook sample javascript code that come with sdk but no luck
i am using the latest 3.2.2 SDK

```
require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '---------',
  'secret' => '----------',
));

// See if there is a user from a cookie
echo $user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
    $user = null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
header('P3P: CP="CURa ADMa DEVa PSAo PSDo OUR BUS UNI PUR INT DEM STA PRE COM NAV OTC NOI DSP COR"');
require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '---------',
  'secret' => '----------',
));
$querystr=http_build_query($_REQUEST);
// See if there is a user from a cookie
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if(isset($_REQUEST['code'])) {

            if(!empty($_REQUEST['code'])) {
setcookie("access_token", $_REQUEST['code'], time()+120);
            } 
            echo ("<script> top.location.href='<YOUR APP URL>'</script>");
            exit;
}

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
    $user = null;
  }
}else {
$scope='email';

    $params = array(
            'redirect_uri' => 'YOUR SITE URL(WHere app is hosted)',
            'display' => 'page',
            'scope' => $scope
        );
    $loginurl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);

     echo ("<script> top.location.href='".$loginurl."'</script>");
     exit;
}
```

Comment: Still no luck
As $user = $facebook->getUser(); always returns 0 so it keeps on reloading

Comment: In which browser you are testing?

Comment: mozilla , chrome same issue in both

Comment: User this line- echo ("<script> top.location.href='<YOUR APP URL>'</script>"); instead of- echo ("<script> top.location.href='<YOUR APP URL>?".$querystr."'</script>"); I have changed the code also.

Comment: Its weird. Then Check if you getting the access_token in your query string or fragment in the permissions tab of your app settings. It should be set to query string. Or add   'cookie' => true in facebook object as $facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
  'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
  'cookie' => true,
));

Comment: yes  'cookie' => true is there and permissions are also fine, i tried with 2-3 different apps but it isnt working